# How to get all SVN commits that do not include Jira bug key in the comment?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, jira, atlassian-fisheye

I have Jira and Fisheye setup so that I can include Jira key in the commit comment ([Smart Commits](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+Smart+Commits)). Fisheye will link source code and Jira issue mentioned in the commit.

I would not like to use something like [JIRA Commit Acceptance Plugin](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/wiki/display/CMMT/JIRA+Commit+Acceptance) to decline commits without Jira keys. As it is too restrictive. But would still like to monitor commits without Jira keys.

How to get a report of all SVN commits that do not include Jira bug Key in the comment?

Comment: Would creating a post-commit hook that looks at the `svn:log` revision property of a revision, and email you (or someone who's interested) if there's no Jira ticket number in the commit comment be good enough?

Comment: David, yes that would be another good solution. Thank you.

Comment: And if you want to get fancy you can convert the regex that JIRA defines as an issue key to an Emacs regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run following command on UNIX in the directory with your working copy:

```
svn log | grep -v '\--' | awk 'ORS=(NR%3)?" ":"\n"' | grep -v "[ISSUE_PREFIX]"
```

where `[ISSUE_PREFIX]` is your JIRA issue prefix. For example, `JPA` for such issues as JPA-123.

It will have following output:

```
r33 | user3 | 2011-12-21 16:29:29 +0200 (Wed, 21 Dec 2011) | 1 line  Third commit log without JIRA key
r22 | user2 | 2011-12-21 16:28:19 +0200 (Wed, 21 Dec 2011) | 1 line  Second commit log without JIRA key
r11 | user1 | 2011-12-21 16:27:18 +0200 (Wed, 21 Dec 2011) | 1 line  First commit log without JIRA key
```